# wc character count seems inflated by 1

Tags: linux, wc

When I try this:

```
echo "hi" | wc -c
```

I'd expect a character count of 2, but I actually get 3.  Can someone explain why it isn't 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo will add a newline characterafter the output by default. Use *echo -n* to avoid this. Also wc -c will count bytes, use wc -m for character count.